# 3D Complex Matrix Iteration and Data manipulation

Tags: matrix, pascal

I have achieved the desired result, but I'm trying to find a more elegant solution.  Right now, it's a little hard coded and that's not good practice.

**NOTE:** This is an old Robot Language that resembles PASCAL.

Problem: I have a 3D Matrix of STRUCTS.  4 X 4 X 9, but I'm just focusing on the first 4 X 4.  The STRUCT has data members I need to manipulate.

GlobalTub[i, j, k].calcPos  ----This member is a type of position with 6 REALS (XYZWPR)

Initializing through the matrix is no problem.  Just a simple nested FOR loop.

```
--Matrix Size
--numOfTubs = (X_CNT * Y_CNT * Z_CNT)
fCnt = 0        
--Init Matrix
FOR i = 1 TO X_CNT DO       
    FOR j = 1 TO Y_CNT DO
        FOR k = 1 TO Z_CNT DO
            InitPos(GlobalTub[i, j, k].foundPos, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1)
            InitPos(GlobalTub[i, j, k].nextPos, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1)
            InitPos(GlobalTub[i, j, k].calcPos, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1)                       
            GlobalTub[i, j, k].inPlace = FALSE              
            --Assing Tub Number Colmun Major
            fCnt = fCnt + 1
            GlobalTub[i, j, k].tubNum = fCnt
        ENDFOR
    ENDFOR      
ENDFOR
```

Now I have to "palletize" this matrix of STRUCTS.  Right now I'm just using a hard coded flow for iterating 4 STRUCTS in X, shift over in Y, and then continue to the next 4.

```
    --Used for Testing
--1 to 4
FOR i = 1 to 4 DO
    TubPos[i] = tempXYZ
    tempXYZ.X = tempXYZ.X + (xPitch + xTolerance)
ENDFOR

tempXYZ = TubPos[1]
tempXYZ.Y = tempXYZ.Y + (yPitch + yTolerance)

-- 5 to 8
FOR i = 1 to 4 DO
    TubPos[i + 4] = tempXYZ
    tempXYZ.X = tempXYZ.X + (xPitch + xTolerance)
ENDFOR
```

How could one achieve this with a nested FOR loop?[Pallet of Parts](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5KvYw.png)

Answer (score 1):

I answered my own question....just hammered it out.

```
--Init Loop Counter 
fCnt = 1
FOR j = 1 TO Y_CNT DO
    --Place 4 positions in X 
    FOR i = 1 to X_CNT DO
        TubPos[fCnt] = tempXYZ
        tempXYZ.X = tempXYZ.X + (xPitch + xTolerance)
        fCnt = fCnt + 1
    ENDFOR
    --Shift Y position for next 4 Rows
    tempXYZ = TubPos[fCnt-1]
    tempXYZ.X = tempXYZ.X - ((xPitch + xTolerance) * (X_CNT - 1))
    tempXYZ.Y = tempXYZ.Y + (yPitch + yTolerance)
ENDFOR
```

Here are my Output
[Positions](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rzEzw.jpg)